# How to run all Capybara tests as if all scenarios were tagged with "@javascript"

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I can add the @javascript tag on individual scenarios, as well on entire features (by adding the tag to the top of each feature file). This works well, but instead of repeating the tag in every file, I'd like Capybara to treat all feature files as if the tag existed. The suite uses Poltergeist:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

I'd like to stick with this driver (to minimize changes), but don't see a way to configure it to always execute javascript. Is there a way to globally set javascript "on"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-tagged tests run with Capybara.default_driver so

```
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
```

would make all tests use poltergeist by default.  If there were any specific scenarios you wanted to use the original default rack_test driver you could then tag them with @rack_test (assuming you're using `require 'capybara/cucumber'`)

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
describe "Some test", :js => true do
 it "bla bla" do
  #your test
 end
end
```

This way, JS will be enabled in every test.

Comment: by the OPs use of @javascript it looks they are using cucumber so this example isn't really relevant

Comment: Tom is right, but I'm curious . . . doesn't this approach require repeating the ":js => true" in every spec?

Comment: @ToddR With RSpec you can set it on higher level blocks, however it would still require it at least once per file - setting Capybara.default_driver would also work with RSpec - and to override you can specify `:driver => :rack_test`  as metadata - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L29

Comment: yes, tom is right. I din't know you were using cucumber